unable to set specific timestamp for data points in Influxdb using Python
import pandas as pd
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WriteOptions
import influxdb_client, os
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS, WritePrecision
from dotenv import dotenv_values
# Environment variables 
token = dotenv_values(".env")["INFLUXDB_TOKEN"]
#configurations
org = "Aquilo"
url = "http://localhost:8086"
# Initialize the InfluxDB client
write_client = InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org)
# Load the dataset
file_path = "steamData sales.xlsx"
steam_data = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Get the write API
write_api = write_client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
# Iterate through the dataset
for index, row in steam_data.iterrows():
    game_id = row['steam Id']
    date_str = row['Date']
    value = row['random_forest_all（K）']
    # Convert date string to datetime object and then to Unix timestamp in nanoseconds
    date = pd.to_datetime(date_str)
    timestamp_ns = int(date.timestamp() * 1e9)
    
    point = (
        Point("app-history")
        .tag("steam_appid", game_id)
        .tag("type", "sales")
        .field("value", value)
        # even use a fix number like 1715872829, it still won't work
        .time(timestamp_ns, write_precision=WritePrecision.NS)
    )
    write_api.write(bucket="default", org="Aquilo", record=point)


this line of code just won't work, I could not write the data in with this in my code.time(timestamp_ns, write_precision=WritePrecision.NS) ,but as long as I remove this line of code, the entire code ran successfully with the data writing in
Does anybody know why? and just wonder how to fix it.and Thank you so much !
